# How to take count of distinct rows which have a specific column with NULL values is all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table CodeResult as follows:

[image]

Here we can notice that Code 123 alone has a Code2, that has a value in Result. I want to take a count of distinct Codes that has no values at all in Result. Which means, in this example, I should get 2.

I do not want to use group by clause because it will slow down the query.

Below code gives wrong result:
`Select count(distinct code) from CodeResult where Result is Null`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Tip: Performance questions benefit from including the _actual execution plan_. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 2):

One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select code
      from t
      group by code
      having max(result) is null
     ) c;
```

A more clever method doesn't use a subquery.  It counts the number of distinct codes and then removes the ones that have a result:

```
select ( count(distinct code) -
         count(distinct case when result is not null then code end )
       )
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't avoid a GROUP BY: In all DBMSs I know, the query plan you get from a:

`SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM tab;` ,

is the same as the one for:

`SELECT a,b,c FROM tab GROUP BY a,b,c;`

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return each of the `Code` values for which there are no corresponding non-NULL values in `CodeResult`:

```
select distinct Code
  from CodeResult as CR
  where not exists
    ( select 42 from CodeResult as iCR where iCR.Code = CR.Code and iCR.CodeResult is not NULL );
```

Counting the rows is left as an exercise for the reader.